# Yii2 access class from within the class

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to use the findOn from within the class that I want to search. Is this possible or is there a better way?

```
class CmsSettings extends ActiveRecord
{

   public static function tableName()
   {
       return 'cms_settings';
   }

   //not working
   public static function run(){

       $results = CmsSettings::findOn(1):

       return $results;

   }

   // not working
   public static function check(){

       $results = CmsSettings::findOn(1):

       if($results->somesetting){
          return true;
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: `self` or `static`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self`

Refer [findOne()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#findOne()-detail)

```
class CmsSettings extends ActiveRecord
{
   public static function tableName()
   {
      return 'cms_settings';
   }

   public static function run() 
   {
      $results = self::findOne(1);
      return $results;
   }

   public static function check() 
   {
      $results = self::findOne(1);

      if ($results->somesetting) {
         return true;
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `static::findOne(1)`. By using `self` or `CmsSettings` you are just hardcoding returned type, which makes this class less flexible and will give you unexpected results on inheritance. For example if you create child model which extends your class:

```
class CmsSettings extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function run() {
        $results = CmsSettings::findOne(1);

        return $results;
    }

    // ...
}

class ChildCmsSettings extends CmsSettings {

}
```

You expect that `ChildCmsSettings::run()` will return instance of `ChildCmsSettings`. Wrong - you will get `CmsSettings`. But if you write this method with using `static`:

```
public static function run() {
    $results = static::findOne(1);

    return $results;
}
```

You will get instance of class which you're used for call `run()` - `ChildCmsSettings`.